# SQL Stored Procedure select statement

Tags: sql-server

I have another field in my database table called FileName, I want the record to be selected by FileName. What should I add to the code.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spx_Pager]
@PageNo int = 1,
@ItemsPerPage int = 2,
@TotalRows int out,
@f_name nvarchar(50)

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE
@StartIdx int,
@SQL nvarchar(max),  
@SQL_Conditions nvarchar(max),   
@EndIdx int

IF @PageNo < 1 SET @PageNo = 1
IF @ItemsPerPage < 1 SET @ItemsPerPage = 10

SET @StartIdx = (@PageNo -1) * @ItemsPerPage + 1
SET @EndIdx = (@StartIdx + @ItemsPerPage) - 1
SET @f_name = (@f_name)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT FilePath
            FROM (
            SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS Row, * 
                  FROM  tblFiles ) AS tbl WHERE  Row >= ' 
                    + CONVERT(varchar(9), @StartIdx) + ' AND
                   Row <=  ' + CONVERT(varchar(9), @EndIdx)
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

SET @SQL = 'SELECT @TotalRows=COUNT(*) FROM tblFiles' 
EXEC sp_executesql 
    @query = @SQL, 
    @params = N'@TotalRows INT OUTPUT', 
    @TotalRows = @TotalRows OUTPUT 
END
```

Comment: why do you use dynamic sql?

Comment: Another field in what table? You need to elaborate on this.

Comment: The same table "tblFiles"

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give me much to go on.  But is this what you need?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spx_Pager]
@PageNo int = 1,
@ItemsPerPage int = 2,
@TotalRows int out,
@f_name nvarchar(50)

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE
@StartIdx int,
@SQL nvarchar(max),  
@SQL_Conditions nvarchar(max),   
@EndIdx int

IF @PageNo < 1 SET @PageNo = 1
IF @ItemsPerPage < 1 SET @ItemsPerPage = 10

SET @StartIdx = (@PageNo -1) * @ItemsPerPage + 1
SET @EndIdx = (@StartIdx + @ItemsPerPage) - 1
SET @f_name = (@f_name)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT FilePath
        FROM (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS Row, * 
              FROM  tblFiles ) AS tbl WHERE  Row >= ' 
                + CONVERT(varchar(9), @StartIdx) + ' AND
               Row <=  ' + CONVERT(varchar(9), @EndIdx) + ' AND
               FileName = @file_name'
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

SET @SQL = 'SELECT @TotalRows=COUNT(*) FROM tblFiles' 
EXEC sp_executesql 
    @query = @SQL, 
    @params = N'@TotalRows INT OUTPUT', 
    @TotalRows = @TotalRows OUTPUT,
    @file_name = @f_name
END
```

Comment: I tried the above code but the error I got is Must declare the scalar variable "f_name"

Comment: I updated my answer.  I think the problem you're having is how to use parameters in dynamic SQL.  If my answer doesn't work check out this link, it should help. http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-use-and-pass-parameters-to-dynamic-SQL-in-SQL-Server.aspx.